# Trying to use InsertFile Method to APPEND to Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Active Document is called “FinalDocument”

The following is in a loop (ie. Report1, Report2, etc..)

```
  DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acPreview, , "Report1”

  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatRTF, “WordDoc1”

  ActiveDocument.Content.InsertFile FileName:=WordDoc1, Range:="", _ 
  ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

I am successfully getting text from Report1 to FinalDocument.

My problem is that on every pass throught loop, InsertFile is REPLACING text.

I want to APPEND Text from Report1 to FinalDocument thereby building FinalDocument one pass at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You should work with a `Range` object so that you can target the insertion point. First, set the`Range` to the entire document, then "collapse" it to a point - think of it like pressing the right-arrow key to make a selection a blinking cursor at the end of the selection.

For example:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd. 'Or use 0
rng.InsertFile FileName:=WordDoc1, Range:="", _ 
   ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertFile FileName:=WordDoc1, Range:="", _ 
  ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

Comment: And where the file is inserted will depend on where the Selection is, which may not be the end of the document...

Comment: Fantastic!  Works like a charm now!  I spent about 8 hours on this and you solved my problem.  I looked everywhere for this solution to no avail.  Thank you!