# How to set curser at the end of Word Document from VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, copy-paste

I am doing Copy/Paste for tables from word document to another Word document via VB.Net, but it either keeps two line in between or merge the table.

I am utilizing VB.Net in automating Word document, I am copying one formatted table from a word document, and then paste it into a different word document.

the problem here is that I have to put a "separater" between the newly pasted table and the one pasted earlier, otherwise word will merge the two (and will keep merging every single newly pasted table).

I tried to put this code before Pasting

```
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdLine, 0)
oWord.Selection.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdLineBreak)
oWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault)
```

it worked fine but it puts two line instead of one.

appreciate if anyone give me a way to keep Pasting (or even adding new paragragh) remain always at the end of the document (with only one line-width separation)

Comment: This is really something of an FAQ - the information in the answer is already on the site a number of times. For example: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use InsertFile Method to APPEND to Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146532/trying-to-use-insertfile-method-to-append-to-word-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a very acceptable solution

instead of using

```
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdLine, 0)
oWord.Selection.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdLineBreak)
oWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault)
```

to insert a break, I used the following code, and it worked perfectly

```
With oWord.Selection
    .Collapse(Direction:=Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
    .InsertParagraph()
    .Collapse(Direction:=Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
End With
```

hope this be useful for anyone facing same problem